# Can we report abuse on suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

It might be rare, but [I just saw this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/68531):

> Income For Life Oppointunity:dot.ws is it;Just like .com;this is where you make real money,click the link below and go for premium,that's where you make the money: [site]

It came from a registered user, [which is abusing making more edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/68558):

> Income For Life Oppointunity:dot.ws is it;Just like .com;this is where you make real money,click the link below and go for premium,that's where you make the money: [site]

Should we do something about this instead of just reject the edit?

Comment: That is a new low in spammer behavior.  Account destroyed.

Comment: Good point, I also see this from time to time.

Comment: Not that destroying the account is an incorrect response, but it also seems possible (perhaps even likely) that this is a result of their account being compromised.

Comment: @jamietre: That is a valid point to bring up, but I did check the account before destroying it.  This was the only activity from that account.

Comment: @jamietre: You can't destroy an account above a certain (low, I believe) reputation.

Comment: If I remember well, an account with a reputation higher than 499 cannot be destroyed; destroying an account is reserved to those users who didn't contribute, if not with spam, or acting like this user.

Answer (score 21):

Reject the edit,

then flag the post with type "other", giving details of the edit in the "flag details" field.

Comment: Just remember to open the question in different tab, if you're the second rejecter it will vanish.

Comment: @Shadow: scroll back up to the top of the list of suggested edits -- you'll find all the accepted and rejected edit suggestions when you were the decisive vote.

Comment: @sarnold is this new feature? Thanks anyway, great tip!

Comment: @Shadow, I'm not sure how long it's been there, but I think it's been there for as long as I've seen the 10k+ suggested-edit queue. It's been really handy to have them still available on the page, even after accepting good edits there is usually more that can be cleaned up. :)