# Suggested edits dialog needs a Report button

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, reporting

The Suggested edits dialog needs a fourth button: Reject and report to moderators.

[image: Suggested edits choices]

Else after we reject it it might not stay around on our screen for us to figure out how to report it.

Comment: I do agree. However, if you do need to contact a moderator for an edit, you can raise a flag on any post (e.g., the one that was edited or even one of your own) and put a link to the problematic edit in the textbox along with explanation what the problem is.  It's not ideal but it should serve you for the 6-8 time units it takes to create this feature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we report abuse on suggested edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96848/can-we-report-abuse-on-suggested-edits)

Comment: Of note, suggested edits that get rejected as spam do feed into an automated system that blocks edits, and causes the edit to not be visible to logged-out users.

Comment: Well, one feels that if one chooses "reject", the offending message might fly away never to be seen again. Thus no way to subsequently sit down and figure out how to take the second separate step to report it. Thus my idea of a "two in one" button.

Comment: @RobertLongson It seems that post merely points out the problem, whereas this one is a feature request for a solution to that problem. The same workaround (Reject, then flag) suggested here in the comments is the accepted answer there.

Comment: @RobertLongson That question, while tagged as a feature request at the time you voted to close, doesn't actually ask for it to be implemented. The title of that question just ask if it's possible to report abuse ([tag:support]), and its body just asks if something should be done ([tag:discussion]). I've retagged that question so its tags match its title and body and am moving to leave this open.

Comment: Also in
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96848/can-we-report-abuse-on-suggested-edits#comment243677_96849 we see once one answers the current dialog the item indeed flies away.